# Highlight rows by non-blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How could I highlight rows by non-blank until the True value in col A changes?

[image]

I tried:

```
=iseven(match($A1,unique($A$1:$A$15),0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=isodd(countif(A$2:$A2,true))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ISODD(INDEX(SCAN(,$A$2:$A,LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)),ROW()-1))
```

[image]

The formula is simply doing a cumulative sum on A2:A and highlighting the rows corresponding to odd values

[image]